# How to updated accessory assets and move object align with others

Tags: modeling

I dont know how to connect accessory assets, that can't show Cables,boards,layout etc....

[image]

[image]

And also, when i move the object , how can object align with others
[image]

Comment: Hello, there, Oliver, welcome to BSE. To conform to  of the structure of SE sites, please split this post up, so you're asking one question at a time.  Try to make it super-clear what you're asking in each case. A good way is to illustrate the _contrast_ between what you've got, and what you want, in a very simple-minded way.